# Swagger endpoint not accessible

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I have a spring mvc project that uses gradle to build the project.

I used the steps described [here](https://github.com/wkennedy/swagger4spring-web-example) in this project.

The build.gradle file has the following entry for swagger:

```
  compile (libraries.swagger){
    exclude group:'org.slf4j', module:'slf4j-log4j12'
    exclude group:'org.slf4j', module:'slf4j-api'
    exclude group:'junit', module:'junit'
  }
```

The configuration for swagger is done in the project build.gradle as below:

```
swagger: "com.knappsack:swagger4spring-web:0.3.3"
```

My controller for the documetation end point is:

```
import com.knappsack.swagger4springweb.controller.ApiDocumentationController;
import com.wordnik.swagger.model.ApiInfo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * This is an example of how you might extend the ApiDocumentationController in order to set your
 * own RequestMapping (instead of the default "/api") among other possibilities.  Going this route,
 * you do not necessarily have to define the controller in your servlet context.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/documentation")
public class SwaggerDocumentationController extends ApiDocumentationController {

  public SwaggerDocumentationController() {
    setBaseControllerPackage("com.controller");
    setBaseModelPackage("com.domain");
    setApiVersion("v1");

    ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("swagger",
        "This is a basic web app for demonstrating swagger",
        "http://localhost:9999/terms", "http://localhost:9999/contact", "MIT",
        "http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT");
    setApiInfo(apiInfo);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String documentation() {
    return "documentation";
  }
}
```

And then I try to access the endpoints for documentation as: `http://localhost:9999/myApp/documentation/test`

`test` is the mapping mentioned inside the controller like below:

```
@Api(value = "test",
    description = "A test controller to see if the services are up and running.")
@RequestMapping(value = {"/test"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
```

I get a 404 not found error while accessing the documentation URL above. Am I missing something?

Please do let me know if any more information is required.

Please help !!

Comment: Experts, I am using JDK 7 on my local.

Answer (score 0):

I have user swagger-springmvc and its working fine. You can try it from following url
https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc